# MainWindow and UserControl, event handling on user control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have MainWindow and DataDetails user control. DataDetails is displayed inside MainWindow on the right side of the window and is rendered using xaml

```
<Views:DataDetails />
```

MainWindow and DataDetails both uses viewmodels and I want to leave codebehind intact. So I use commands for event handling, but I have problem with this approach. Click event on MainWindow is working properly, same approach on DataDetails not working, here's the code

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
...
<Button Name="btnSearch" 
        Command="{Binding  SearchByCommand, Mode=OneWay}"> Search </Button>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public ICommand SearchByCommand
{
    get
    {
       if (_SearchByCommand == null)
       {
           _SearchByCommand = new RelayCommand(
              x => this.LoadData(this.SearchBy),
              x => { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SearchText); }
          );
       }
       return _SearchByCommand;
    }
 }
```

LoadData method is not shown here to reduce amount of code, again this works inisde MainWindow.

Inside MainWindow.xaml I've added DataDetails user control with `<Views:DataDetails />`, inside window tag element I've added this namespace, so this user control appears properly inside MainWindow. Inside DataDetails I have button click event wired to Command SaveDataCommand and command itself inside DataDetailsViewModel.

**DataDetails.xaml**

```
<Button Name="btnSave" 
            Command="{Binding  SaveDataCommand, Mode=OneWay}"> Save data</Button>
```

**DataDetailsViewModel**

```
public ICommand SaveDataCommand
{
    get
    {
        _SaveDataCommand = new RelayCommand(
             x=>this.SaveData(), null);
             return _SaveDataCommand;
    }            
}
```

again this method (SaveData) is not shown here to reduce amount of code. On debugging this SaveDataCommand is never hitted, on button click nothing happen. What I'm missing here?

Comment: Where do you set DataDetails DataContext to be DataDetailsViewModel? Is DataDetailsViewModel a property of MainWindowViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you establishing the VM that should be bound to your nested user control? In the constructor for the view? There are a slew of ways you can do this, one I've often used is to expose the 'details view model' as a property on the main VM, and then set the data context appropriately:

```
<Views:DataDetails DataContext={Binding DataDetails} />
```

And then your main VM has a property:

```
public DataDetailsViewModel DataDetails { get { return _dataDetailsViewModel; } }
```

Of course, there are a lot of different ways you could establish the data context for your details view, above is just one of many options.